# Put fractured GIT history back together

Tags: git, git-merge

**Background**

I was working on a project on the road over Thanksgiving break with no internet connection. I used a DropBox sync rather then `git` to move the files to my laptop before I left. Bad idea.  the .git directory didn't come over correctly and without Google the only thing I could manage to do was to blow away the whole thing and start a new git repository.

I am back from vacation and can now get to GitHub which has the original history.

**Question**

How can I apply the commits in the new repository to the original repository?

**Illustration**

```
        d -- e -- f -- *  <= working tree when bad things happened
      /
a -- b -- c   (Original git repository) 
      \
       g -- h


a' -- b' -- c' -- d'  (new repo with a' = *)


        d -- e -- f -- a' -- b' -- c' -- d'
      /                                    \
a -- b -- c -- (desired result) ------------m
      \
       g -- h
```

Comment: Check out the latest working copy to a new directory. Then drop the whole project over the top. Then commit. It should only commit the changes. You probably wont be able to keep each individual commit doing it that way though.

Comment: I think the solution is to add the Github repo as a remote, then rebase your new commits on top of it.  Not confident enough that this will work to post as an answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

You essentially want to apply each patch in sequence to the original repository.  This would be a royal pain if you had to `git-am` each one manually!  But Git is awesome.  It's fairly straightforward if you keep in mind that `git-rebase` works at the patch level, not the commit level, and will basically do all the work for you.

Go to your working repository and check out the branch you were on when you decided to Dropbox the project.  I strongly recommend that your working directory be clean; if it isn't, you should stash it (and know how to use `git-reflog`) before continuing.

Once you're ready to replay your work, add the new repository as a remote.  This works equally well if you're using a temporary remote repo (on GitHub for example) or a directory elsewhere on your local computer.  Now, assuming you called your remote `turkey`, run the following commands:

```
$ git fetch turkey
$ git rebase HEAD turkey/master
$ git checkout -b rebased
```

Now you have a new branch, `rebased`, that has your Thanksgiving work in it.  I'm not entirely sure why Git doesn't go ahead and move the old branch pointer, but whatever:  You can merge the new `rebased` into your old branch if you like, and the old branch should just fast forward.

At this point, you can delete the remote and push to GitHub.

Comment: This failed with:
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
fatal: Could not parse object '200dddf914aa8e6787e9d778902e72adc45b0589^'
Unknown exit code (128) from command: git-merge-recursive 200dddf914aa8e6787e9d778902e72adc45b0589^ -- HEAD 200dddf914aa
8e6787e9d778902e72adc45b0589

Comment: Uh oh.  I have no idea; that sounds like your repository is corrupt.  What happens if you run `git fsck` (on both repos)?